# Hacer metodo post desde android kotlin

Tags: android-studio, api

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de prueba sin vistas ni nada solo es una prueba para introducir un usuario a una base de datos mediante un metodo post con retrofit. El problema es que me da error porque dice que no se puede conectar a la api.

Este es mi codigo:
Interfaz del servicio api

```
interface ServicioAPI {
    @POST("usuarios")
    fun crearUsuario(@Body usuario: Usuario): Call<Void>
}
```

data class Usuario

```
data class Usuario(
    val idUsuario: Int,
    val nombre: String,
    val email: String,
    val contrasenia: String,
    val fechaRegistro: LocalDateTime
)
```

y main activity:

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://localhost:7150/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val servicioAPI = retrofit.create(ServicioAPI::class.java)
        val usuario = Usuario(
            idUsuario = 1,
            nombre = "Juan",
            email = "juan@gmail.com",
            contrasenia = "contraseña123",
            fechaRegistro = LocalDateTime.now()
        )


        servicioAPI.crearUsuario(usuario).enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onResponse: ${response.body()}")
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    // La llamada fue exitosa, se ha creado el usuario
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Usuario creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    // La llamada falló por algún motivo
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {
                // La llamada falló debido a un error de red u otro tipo de error
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

Me da el error de Failed to connection with localhost. La api es una creada por mi que esta corriendo en visual studio a la misma vez por lo que esta activa. Y funciona porque desde postman si puede insertar usuarios. Tambien estoy seguro de que la ruta es correcta. Muchas gracias

La api para realizar el metodo post necesita un usuario con los mismos datos que el de la dataClass y no devuelve nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado el problema. Yo siempre me he conectado a una api desde el mismo ordenador en el que estaba ejecutandose la api o en su defecto a mis propias apis que tenía subida a azure. Por ejemplo tenía la api arrancada en un proyecto y desde otro proyecto por ejemplo de angular me conectaba a esa api por lo que la ruta era localhost:etc.

Bueno a lo que vamos el fallo es que claro al esta api aun no estar subida a azure (porque cunado esta en local es más fácil debuguearla en caso de que tenga fallos) mi ruta para conectarme a la api en la aplicación kotlin es localhost:ect. Sin embargo ahora la api no se esta ejecutando en el mismo dispositivo por lo que el móvil al intentar acceder al localhost da el error de no poder conectarse. Espero que esto les ayude jajajjaja

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://tuUrlDeInternet/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val servicioAPI = retrofit.create(ServicioAPI::class.java)
        val usuario = Usuario(
            idUsuario = 1,
            nombre = "Juan",
            email = "juan@gmail.com",
            contrasenia = "contraseña123",
            fechaRegistro = LocalDateTime.now()
        )
```